# Why do all Giuga numbers have exactly one odd prime factor which is congruent to 1 (mod 4) ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Why do all Giuga numbers have exactly one odd prime factor which is congruent to 1 (mod 4) , with all their other odd prime factors being congruent to 3 (mod 4) ?

only thirteen Giuga Numbers are known.  They are:
30 = 2 · 3 · **5**.

858 = 2 · 3 · 11 · **13**,

1722 = 2 · 3 · 7 · **41**.

66198 = 2 · 3 · 11 · **17** · 59.

2214408306 = 2 · 3 · 11 · 23 · 31 · **47057**,

24423128562 = 2 · 3 · 7 · 43 · **3041** · 4447.

432749205173838 = 2 · 3 · 7 · 59 · 163 · **1381** · 775807,

14737133470010574 = 2 · 3 · 7 · 71 · 103 · **67213** · 713863,

550843391309130318 = 2 · 3 · 7 · 71 · 103 · 61559 · **29133437.**

244197000982499715087866346 = 2 · 3 · 11 · 23 · 31 · **47137** · 28282147·
3892535183,

554079914617070801288578559178 = 2 · 3 · 11 · 23 · 31 · 47059 · **2259696349·**
110725121051,

1910667181420507984555759916338506 = 2 · 3 · 7 · 43 · · · 1831 · 138683 · 2861051·
**1456230512169437.**

4200017949707747062038711509670656632404195753751630609228764416
142557211582098432545190323474818 = 2 · 3 · 11 · 23 .31 · 47059 · 2217342227·
1729101023519 · **8491659218261819498490029296021·**
658254480569119734123541298976556403.

Primes which are congruent to 1 (mod 4 ) are in bold.  Note that for each Giuga number there is exactly one odd prime factor which is congruent to 1 (mod 4).  All the other prime factors are congruent to 3 (mod 4 ).  Is this just a  coincidence ? Or is there a number-theoretic  reason for this ?

Comment: Nice question (+1) What is the definition of a Giuga number ?

Comment: A Giuga Number is a composite number n such that p divides n/p - 1

for every p, prime divisor of n.

Comment: Seems that all Giuga numbers are even and squarefree. It might be a good start to prove that.

Comment: @Peter the wikipedia article shows squarefree; even is a conjecture  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuga_number

Comment: Far above Giuga's waters,
    With its waves of blue,
    Stands our noble Alma Mater,
    Glorious to view.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397447/why-seven-out-of-eight-primary-pseudoperfect-numbers-only-have-odd-prime-factors

Comment: Squarefree is immediate from $p \mid n/p - 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Above_Cayuga's_Waters

Comment: The observed property seems so unusual that there should be some reason. Unfortunately, I do not even have an idea how to show that a Giuga number must have some prime factor of the form $4k+1$

Comment: @Peter An equivalent characterization of Giuga number is that $(\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p) - 1/n$ is an integer.  For every Giuga number we will ever find by computation, that integer is $1$, because getting $>1$ would require thousands(?) of prime factors.  So a more fruitful place to start might be $(\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p) - 1/n = 1$ rather than $p \mid n/p -1$.  Note that this already disambiguates Giuga numbers from primes (which satisfy $p \mid n/p - 1$ but obviously do not satisfy the conjecture).

Comment: The $(\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p) - 1/n$ characterization also helps to explain why even Giuga numbers appear to be more common than odd ones: if you're searching up to, say, 12 prime factors, there are probably a lot fewer combinations of $\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p$ that lie close to $1$ when $1/2$ is excluded.

Comment: Correction: it doesn't necessarily require thousands of prime factors to get $ = 2$, but it probably helps :).  It definitely requires *dozens* of prime factors, which is five times larger than any known Giuga numbers.  I was confusing Giuga numbers with counterexamples to Giuga's conjecture, which must satisfy an additional criterion that heavily restricts the primes that can go into $n$.

Comment: @Peter I can prove that every even Giuga number with $<59$ prime factors has an odd number of prime factors of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: @ErickWong This would be a milestone for the first part, so you can post the proof as a partial answer.

Comment: Maybe this deserves another thread, but reviewing this question and the numbers showed, dont you think it is remarkable the fact that all Giuga numbers seem to be divisible by 6?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer.  I can prove the following (except for one computation that I defer to Wikipedia for a reference).

- If $n$ is a even Giuga number with $<59$ prime factors, then $n$ has an *odd* number of prime factors that are $1$ mod $4$.
- If $n$ is an odd Giuga number, then $\omega(n) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $\omega(n) \ge 14$.

This helps explain that some of the observations in the OP and comments could reasonably be attributed to "small number" phenomena, since the cost of searching for Giuga numbers tends to grow doubly-exponentially with the number of prime factors, so any Giuga number we have found will have a relatively small number of factors.

One major thing this answer *doesn't* explain: why exactly one prime factor?  This pattern seems to hold out in the more general setting of Giuga sequences as studied by Brenton et al, though I wasn't able to find an exhaustive list beyond 7 or 8 terms.  Maybe someone can find a simple refinement that improves "odd" to "congruent to $1$ mod $4$", or maybe there is a clever argument involving quadratic residues.

**Proof:**
First observe that $p \mid \sum_{p\mid n} n/p - 1$ for all $p \mid n$.  We already know $n$ is squarefree, so $n \mid \sum_{p\mid n} n/p - 1$, meaning that $(\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p) - 1/n$ is an integer.  Since the sum of reciprocals of the first $58$ primes is a little under $2$, it is clear that any Giuga number with fewer than $59$ prime factors must satisfy:

$$\left(\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p\right) - 1/n= 1.$$

Suppose $n$ is even, with $r$ prime factors $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ congruent to $1$ mod $4$, and $s$ prime factors $q_1,\ldots,q_s$ congruent to $3$ mod $4$.  Then the above equation, multiplied by $2$, is:

$$ 1 + \frac{2}{p_1} + \cdots + \frac{2}{p_r} + \frac{2}{q_1} + \cdots + \frac{2}{q_s} - \frac{1}{p_1\cdots p_r q_1 \cdots q_s} = 2. $$

The LHS is a $2$-adic integer, so we can look at it mod $4$ (equivalently, we clear out numerators, the computation is basically the same).  Each $\frac{2}{p}$ term contributes a $2$, and a quick computation confirms that $p_1\cdots p_r q_1 \cdots q_s$ is congruent to $1 + 2s \pmod 4$.  Therefore

$$ 1 + 2(r+s) - (1+2s) \equiv 2r \equiv 2 \pmod 4,$$

which is equivalent to $r$ being odd.  This proves that there is at least one prime factor of the form $4k+1$.  Note that the same calculation shows that if ever we found an even Giuga number with $(\sum_{p\mid n} 1/p) - 1/n = 2$, then it must have an *even* number of prime factors of the form $4k+1$, so it's plausible that the initial conjecture in OP is false.

The case where $n$ is odd can be analyzed by the same methods as above, but the conclusion we can draw is that $r+s \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, so $\omega(n) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.  Furthermore, the reciprocal sum of the first $6$ odd primes is $<1$, so we must have $\omega(n) > 6$.  The reciprocal sum of the first $10$ odd primes is only $\approx 1.0657$: this small amount of slack is amenable to a short computer search which exhausts all possible $10$-prime odd solutions, meaning that $\omega(n) \ge 14$ as claimed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuga_number).