# Why seven out of eight Primary pseudoperfect numbers only have odd prime factors which are congruent to $3 \pmod{4}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Why seven out of eight Primary pseudoperfect numbers only have odd prime factors which are  congruent to $3 \pmod{4}$?

Primary pseudoperfect numbers: numbers $n \gt 1$ such that $\frac{1}{n} + \sum_{p | n} \frac{1}{p} = 1$.

Only eight Primary pseudoperfect numbers have been discovered so far. They are:

$2 = 2$

$6 = 2 \cdot 3$

$42 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot  7$

$1806 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot  7 \cdot 43$

$47058 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \cdot  31$

$2214502422 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \cdot  31 \cdot 47059$

$52495396602 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot$ **17** $\cdot$ **101** $\cdot$   **149** $\cdot$       **3109**

$8490421583559688410706771261086 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \cdot  31 \cdot 47059 \cdot 2217342227 \cdot 1729101023519$

> Primes which are congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$ are shown in bold. Note that only one of the known Primary pseudoperfect numbers has odd prime factors which are congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$. Seven out of eight known Primary pseudoperfect numbers don't have any prime factors which are congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$. Is this just a coincidence ?  Or is there a number-theoretic  reason for this ?

Comment: Again a nice question (+1)

Comment: If only eight are known, it's a little early to ask that question.

Comment: Anyway, the numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A054377 where there are several links to the literature. Maybe the question has been discussed there.

Comment: Both the property here and the property in the linked question seem so unusual to me that I think there is some reason. Consider that the numbers here have some structure : The first $4$ form a chain, in which every number is a multiple of the previous numbers, also the fifth, sixth and eight. Such chains have of course better chances to avoid a prime factor of the form $4k+1$ then pure random numbers. The property of the Giuga-numbers is even more surprising.

Comment: Remarkable : It has been shown that there are no more primary pseudoperfect numbers with less than $9$ prime factors.